# Creating DB Links in postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql-9.5, dblink

Tried creating a DB link in POSTGRES SSP SIT Environment, so that I can connect to that Environment from NTE5OF Environment but its throwing an error

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "TO"
LINE 4:   CONNECT TO pcatdev IDENTIFIED BY 'pcatdev' 
                  ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 55

```
CREATE DATABASE LINK SSP_SIT_ONLINE_link 
CONNECT TO pcatdev IDENTIFIED BY 'pcatdev' 
USING libpq 'host=vcm-vvov-east1a-postgre-sit-npd-181.c0ltwolwvb5h.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com dbname=SSP SIT ONLINE';
```

A DB Link SSP_SIT_ONLINE_link should be created

Comment: Where [in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/index.html) did you find that syntax?

Comment: https://www.enterprisedb.com/docs/en/9.3/oracompat/Database_Compatibility_for_Oracle_Developers_Guide.1.048.html

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : Please Let me know if this is not the right format as mentioned in the above manual which I took as reference and why?

Comment: So you are using EnterpriseDB? In that case contact their support. "Stock Postgres" does not support that syntax. You need to use foreign tables there.

Comment: Ok, Thanks, but just for my understanding can I follow the below article for "Stock Postgres", the db link is just used between different Postgres Environments.

http://www.leeladharan.com/postgresql-cross-database-queries-using-dblink

Comment: The DbLink extension is a bit outdated and only useful for ad-hoc queries. The modern replacement are [foreign tables](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createforeigntable.html)